# How do we differentiate y = $\frac{x\sin x}{1+\tan x}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How do we differentiate y = $\frac { x\sin x}{1+\tan x}$ ?

I am confused whether to use product rule for $x\sin x$ first but If do this. Then , when I will use division rule over this since I need to do for $1+\tan x$ also. I would have differentiated $x\sin x$ twice  or division rule for $x\sin x/1+\tan x$ but then I didn’t use product rule first $x\sin x$

Comment: Either way works. You can view it as a product $x$ times $\sin x/(1+\tan x)$, and then do a quotient rule as part of that, or as a quotient of $x \sin x$ and $1 + \tan x$, and then do a product rule for part of that.

Comment: @RobertTheTutor Ohk. I didn’t understand the second part you told . First one I got .

Comment: What happens when you try both ways?   Do you get different answers?

Comment: Please do not use tags that are inappropriate!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are four approaches. The first two are (I think) what you are deliberating over. The latter two are techniques that, for what its worth, avoid using the quotient rule.

1. You can view it as $\frac{[x\sin x]}{1+\tan x}$ and use the quotient rule first: $$\frac{(1+\tan x)\frac{d}{dx}[x\sin x]-[x\sin x]\frac{d}{dx}(1+\tan x)}{(1+\tan x)^2}$$ and then you need to use the product rule.
2. You can view it as $x\cdot\left[\frac{\sin x}{1+\tan x}\right]$ and use the product rule first: $$\frac{d}{dx}x\cdot \left[\frac{\sin x}{1+\tan x}\right]+x\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\left[\frac{\sin x}{1+\tan x}\right]$$ and then you need to use the quotient rule.
3. You can multiply to get $y(1+\tan x)=x\sin x$ and then use the product rule on each side: $$\frac{d}{dx}y\cdot(1+\tan x)+y\cdot\frac{d}{dx}(1+\tan x)=\frac{d}{dx}x\cdot\sin x+x\cdot\frac{d}{dx}\sin x$$ and then you can solve for $y'$. That will leave a $y$ hanging around, which you can substitute the orignial expression for.
4. You can apply $\ln\lvert\cdot\rvert$ to get $\ln\lvert y\rvert=\ln\lvert x\rvert+\ln\lvert\sin(x)\rvert-\ln\lvert1+\tan x\rvert$ and now differentiate using the chain rule: $$\frac{y'}{y}=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{\frac{d}{dx}\sin(x)}{\sin x}-\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(1+\tan x)}{1+\tan x}$$ That will leave a $y$ hanging around, which you can substitute the original expression for.

Comment: For the 1st one , we need to use product rule only for xsinx right ?

Comment: @Rider That's right.

Answer (score 2):

In general, if you need $(\frac{AB}{C})'$, you can view that as $A$ times $B/C$, or as $B$ times $A/C$, or as $AB$ divided by $C$.  Once you choose that, you find that you need another rule, quotient in the first two cases, or product in the last, in order to finish the overall rule you are doing.

So, $$\big(AB/C\big)' = ( A \cdot (B/C) )' = A' \cdot (B/C) + A \cdot (B/C)' = A'B/C + A \cdot (CB' - BC')/C^2$$

or for the last case, you can do
$$\big(AB/C\big)' = ( (AB)/C) )' = \frac{C \cdot (AB)' - (AB)C'}{C^2} = \frac{C\cdot[A'B + AB'] - (AB)C'}{C^2}$$

In your case, $A= x, B = \sin x$, and $C = 1 + \tan x$.

Answer (score 0):

A good mnemonic is "low d high minus high d low, down below the square must go".
You could use the quotient rule.  Get $\dfrac {(\sin x+x\cos x)(1+\tan x)-x\sin x (\sec^2 x)}{(1+\tan x)^2} $, then try to simplify.

I don't see much point in quibbling over whether to use the product rule or the quotient rule, it all amounts to the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself: When evaluating the right hand side, what's the **last** operation you do, a product or a division? The answer to that question tells which which derivative rule to use **first**, the product rule or the division rule.